# One pack inoperative - effect on cabin temp?

Tags: airline-operations

When one Pack  is inoperative on the ground and/or during flight , is there a consequence for the cabine temperature ? (temp likely too high or too low, i.e. not able to regulate the cabin temp properly ?

Comment: Which airplane are you referring to?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please be nice to a new person on the site.